# How to convert a list of variables into numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a number of variables being passed into a function, V1, V2, etc and i want to automatically convert these to numpy arrays in as few lines as possible. These variables will be lists of numbers and i have already checked that they are either a list or a numpy array already

I have tried packing them in a list, i.e. `newlist= [V1, V2, . . .]` and then iterating over the list:

```
for i in range(len(newlist)):
    inputs[i] = np.asarray(inputs[i])
```

but this method only replaces the elements in the list with copies. 
What i would like to do is convert each variable to an array as if i had performed the following operation:

```
V1 = np.asarray(V1)
```

If V1 is a list, it is an array after this statement, but i would like to avoid having to write as many of these statements as there are variables.

thanks for your help

Comment: Lists don't contain variables, they contain objects.

Comment: You should just use the list.

Comment: thanks, i guess this was the limitation that I didn't understand was there. I guess the only way would then be to put the name of the variable in the list and then run a python executable command line to run,  V1 = np.asarray(V1).  Is there a way to get the return the namespace variable as a string. I seem to remember there is a way to do it in Matlab.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you are getting at. It seems quite trivial to solve your problem, put your arrays in a container, and use that container.

Answer (score 0):

```
newlist= [np.asarray(item) for item in newlist]
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing as the code they provided